# How to pass child useState to Parent in React? Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react, use-state

Whenever I wanted to Delete a certain product it will directly go to the Index page(Home page) and I wanted to show the Message modal saying "Your product has been delete" and after 5 seconds it will disappear.

here is my code for ProductSummary.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Header, Button, Modal } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import axios from 'axios';
import urlLink from '../../utils/baseUrl';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

function ProductAttributes({ description, _id }) {
    const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
    const [messagener, setMessagener] = useState(false);
    const router = useRouter();
async function deleteProduct() {
    // const url = `${urlLink}/api/product`;
    // const payload = { params: { _id } };
    // await axios.delete(url, payload);
    router.push('/');
    setMessagener(true);
    setMessagener(() => setMessagener(false), 5000);
}

return (
    <>
        <Header as="h3">About this product</Header>
        <p>{description}</p>
        <Button
            icon="trash alternate outline"
            color="red"
            content="Delete Product"
            onClick={() => setModal(true)}
        />
        <Modal open={modal} dimmer="blurring">
            <Modal.Header>Confirm Delete</Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Content>
                <p>Are you sure you want to delete this product?</p>
            </Modal.Content>
            <Modal.Actions>
                <Button content="Cancel" onClick={() => setModal(false)} />
                <Button
                    negative
                    icon="trash"
                    labelPosition="right"
                    content="Delete"
                    onClick={deleteProduct}
                />
            </Modal.Actions>
        </Modal>
    </>
);
}
export default ProductAttributes;
```

Note: I just comment out the delete so that whenever I click the delete button the message will show in my Home Page for 5 seconds.  I have successfully delete a product the reason I have comment it out because I only have 20 product in my database and I don't want to delete them or empty out my database.

Here is my Index page (or Home Page) Index.js

```
function Home({ products, messagener }) {
return (
    <Container>
        {messagener ? (
            <Message
                deleted
                icon="checked"
                color="red"
                content=" Product Successfully Deleted"
            />
        ) : (
            ''
        )}
        <ProductList products={products} />
    </Container>
);
}
```

After I delete a product and I have successfully do so I wanted to show just like this in the picture

[image: Product Successfully deleted]

and after 5 seconds it will disappear.

here is my github repositories https://github.com/GrizzlyBear-Michaelangelo/Ecommerce.git for my problem.

Note: I didn't use any state management for this project and I wanted to practice for passing props and events.

Anyone could help me passing child to Parent?

Comment: In react data generally flows in one direction, Parent -> Child. If the parent wants a child to do anything it needs to pass it as prop to the child for it to operate on. In this case it seems you should hold some state in the parent about show/hide the alert, and pass a callback to the child so when an item is delete it can "alert" the parent to do something. You may want to also look into a Toast component that can be invoke from anywhere in the app (uses Context API under the hood).

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest way you can pass the callback method from parent to child. Then the child will call that method with the data you want to set.

```
const Parent = () => {
  ...
  const [messanger, setMessanger] = useState(false);
  ...

  <Child setMessanger={setMessanger}>
}

const Child = (props) => {
  ...
  props.setMessanger(true);
  ...
}
```

Comment: If I do that then the <ProductAttritube /> would be shown to my Home page.

Comment: In my Home page: const [messanger, setMessanger] = useState(false);

Comment: <ProductAttributes setMessanger={setMessanger} />

Comment: {messanger ? (
<Message
deleted
    icon="checked"
                    color="red"
                    content=" Product Successfully Deleted"
                />
) : (
                ''
 )}

Comment: in my ProductAttribute: function ProductAttributes({ description, _id, setMessanger })

Comment: async function deleteProduct() {() => setMessanger(true);}.

Comment: @JmMacatangay I don't follow how lifting the state to the parent and passing a callback shows `ProductAttribute` to your `Home` component. Move `[messagener, setMessagener]` state to `Home` and pass `setMessagener` to `ProductList`, which passes it down eventually to `ProductAttribute`. If there are several components between `Home` and `ProductAttribute` then it suggested to use the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) instead to avoid the issue of "prop drilling".

Comment: Is it possible to pass to  parent's parent's component (two levels of more)

Comment: how to initialize the parent's hook with the initial value contained in the child?

Comment: @assayag.org yes you can pass to components in two or more level. But it recommended to use context api or state manager in this kind of scenario.